# Alignment issue on Firefox and IE on the template I want to use

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a back end developer and have lesser knowledge about the front end, i am trying to develop an application by using below template.

http://p.w3layouts.com/demos/cuisine/web/

This template working absolutely fine, however on firefox and IE its having some alignment issue. I really need help in this, already spent lot of time figuring our whats wrong in the template but no clue, please guide me!!

Comment: Not seeing any alignment issues in the layout sample on my end, (FF 31.2.0), might wanna explain the problem a bit better....

Comment: issue is in latest FF when you open the above link in it, but anyways problem is solved, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.top-header {
    /* margin-top: -456px; */
    position: relative;
    top: -456px;
}
```

Instead of `margin-top`, use `top` and `position: relative;`

Of course, you have to adapt the rest of the code with this method as well :)

Like this for example :

```
.top-grids {
    /* margin-top: 279px; */
    top: -178px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: you are awesome it solved the problem, i will put this logic through out the code as the whole template alignment is messed up due to margin-top, thanks a lot

Comment: you're welcome, don't forget to mark this subject as resolved if it's good for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the response but when I put position: relative; and    top:-456px; its breaking into chrome. When we are fixing the alignment issue in FF and IE then its not working on chrome thats new trouble. :-(

Comment: It's because you have to adapt others elements with negative margins as well like .top-grids
I've edited my answer. Did you erase margin-top negative values when adding top values ?